# Meteor Template events, how to get object that caused event?

Tags: meteor

I have some code similar to the following:

In myapp.html

```
<template name="problems">
    <div class="problems">
        {{#each problems}}
            {{> problem}}
    {{/each}}
    </div>
</template

<template name="problem">
    <div class="problem">
        <div class="problem-text" id={{_id}}>{{text}}</div>
    </div>
</template>
```

In myapp.js

```
Template.problem.events = {
'click .problem-text' : function () {

        var user_id = Session.get('user_id');

        // how to get problem_id of clicked item?
        Router.gotoProblem(user_id, problem_id);    
    }
};
```

In this situation I want to get the id of the  that matched .problem-text and was clicked.

I would like to know the "object" that generated the event?  How do I do this?

Comment: Per Meteor documentation, they receive the current template data in the 'this' object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
Template.problem.events = {
'click .problem-text' : function () {

        var user_id = Session.get('user_id');

        // how to get problem_id of clicked item?
        Router.gotoProblem(user_id, this._id);    
    }
};
```

Answer (score 19):

The selected answer for this question will ONLY get the `_id` , and that too if `_id` is used in templates.

So better use, `event.target`, that will give COMPLETE object. So that can be used with jQuery or MooTools.

```
Template.top_nav.events({
'mousedown, .nav li a': function(evt){
  console.log('the class of object that was clicked is ' + $(evt.target).attr("class"));
 }
})
```

Comment: Just to prevent some errors. Note that using event.target will give you the element clicked, so in this example it could return a span that is a child on the link. Use event.currentTarget to receive the element on which you are listening to.

Answer (score 5):

You can access the problem object with *this* reference:

```
Template.problem.events = {
    /**
     * Handles problem text click.
     * @param {jQuery.Event} event
     */
    'click .problem-text' : function (event) {
      /*
      Here this is a reference to the problem object
      and you have jQuery.Event object as the event argument.
       */
      console.log(this, arguments);

      var user_id = Session.get('user_id');
      var problem = this;

      // how to get problem_id of clicked item?
      Router.gotoProblem(user_id, /** problem_id */problem._id);
    }
  };
```

Comment: I upvoted, because this is the real answer. Using the session for such a thing is a hack.

Comment: Not sure, "this" reference will give you the data from the object retrieved by the helper. I think this question is more related to how to get the html object. In that case "event.target" is the right way. However is nice to have in mind both approaches. Sometimes the "session hack" is used when you want to re-render from reactive data.